# CheckBoxListItem value using javascript in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a page in asp.net where i have populated a checkboxList control from backend and user can check/uncheck items and right after that i want to capture the values of those which are checked and read in a string variable but i am unable to do so. please help

here is the code.

```
function check() {
    var table1 = document.getElementById('<%=cb_Roles.ClientID%>');       
    var chkCheckBoxListItems = table1.getElementsByTagName("input");

    var j = 0;
    var c_value = "";

    if (table1 != null)

        for (var i = 0; i <= chkCheckBoxListItems.length - 1; i++) 
       {
           if (chkCheckBoxListItems[i].checked) {
               c_value = c_value + document.getElementById('<%=cb_Roles.ClientID%>').value + "\n";

 //    tried this also->  c_value = c_value + chkCheckBoxListItems[i].value + "\n";
           }
        }
        alert(c_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're repeatedly fetching the `value` of your `<table>` element instead of the current check box. You probably should write:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chkCheckBoxListItems.length; i++) {
    if (chkCheckBoxListItems[i].checked) {
        c_value += chkCheckBoxListItems[i].value + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: tried your code but the c_value inside alert is keep on coming blank even though selected one or two items :(

Comment: @user239684, that's strange. Are you sure your check boxes actually *have* values?

Comment: yeah it has..as in my C# code behind ive binded by executing the reader object which has values ..doubled check already :)

Comment: when i tried this
if (chkCheckBoxListItems[i].checked) {  
                   //c_value = c_value +   chkCheckBoxListItems[i].innerHTML + "\n";
                   alert("item is   checked"+chkCheckBoxListItems[i].value);  
               }

it is giving me a "on" text in alert...whats that

Comment: Do you mean you used `DataValueField`? Can you actually see those values in the rendered page source?

Comment: <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cb_Roles_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cb_Roles$0" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cb_Roles_0">Control User</label></td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cb_Roles_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cb_Roles$1" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cb_Roles_1">Menu User</label></td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cb_Roles_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cb_Roles$2" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cb_Roles_2">Application User</label></td>

Comment: anyway solved my problem..instead of values i read LABELS and it worked..thanks for ur help Frederic :)